# Transpose Columns in Order using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, transpose

I have an extremely large amount of data needs to be transposed in order using the example on the image below. The left side of the image is how the information comes from the report, and the right side is what I need it to look like.

I have tried to use the Transpose paste special but it results in 3000+ columns of information. I have also tried pivot tables but I get the information out of order.

The three pieces of "Info" are per employee. As it stands now, the lines are vertically but in our end result we should have three rows per employee.

[Transpose Left Original Data Right Outcome Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MUmW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by the below formula

[image: Screenshot]

```
F1 = INDEX($A$1:$A$3,1+QUOTIENT(ROW()-ROW($F$1),3))

G1 = VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$D$3,2+MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),3),FALSE)
```

So if you have 3000 lines of data, the formula should be dragged to 9000 rows.